# Not able to get QueryString in next page after redirecting to another page using Modal

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using asp:Repeater control to show booked rooms in my asp.net application. I'm using Modal to show information when user clicks on 'Checkout' button. Now I'm copying that information from Repeater control to show values in modal's textboxes.

Now when user clicks Checkout & Print Button in the modal, I'm building QueryString to transfer bookingId to another page to generate Crystal Reports. But the problem is that when I'm clicking the button the QueryString is returning null value so the report is not getting generated in the next page.
Anything that can solve this issue?

Below is all the code I used to copy Repeater control DataBound values to Modal Textboxes:

```
$(document).on('click', '.chkmodal', function () {
        var bookingid = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtBI1').text();            
        var room_no = $(this).closest('section').find('.room_no').text();
        var cust_name = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtcustname').text();
        var checkin = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtcin1').text();
        var checkout = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtcout2').text();
        var bal = parseFloat($(this).closest('section').find('.txtbal').text());
        var Nod = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtNOD1').text();
        var advance = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtAdvance1').text();
        var extras = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtExtras').text();
        var Total = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtTotalA').text();
        var CGST = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtCGST1').text();
        var Path = $(this).closest('section').find('.txtImgPath').text();
        /*var balanceAmt = parseFloat($('.txtbalance').val());*/
        var pamt = parseFloat($(this).parent().find('.txtPaidAmt').val());
        var res = pamt - bal;

        $('.txtBI1').val(bookingid);
        //$('.bidnor').val(bookingid);
        $('.txtCName').val(room_no);
        $('.custName').val(cust_name);
        $('.txtcin1').val(checkin);
        $('.txtcout2').val(checkout);
        $('.txtbal').val(bal);
        $('.txtNOD1').val(Nod);
        $('.txtAdvance1').val(advance);
        $('.txtExtras').val(extras);
        $('.txtTotalA').val(Total);
        $('.txtCGST1').val(CGST);
        $('.txtPath').attr("src", Path);
        $('.txtPAIDNOW').val(pamt);
        $('.txtGT').val(res);

    });
```

My Repeater Control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-3 ">
                                        <section class="room">
                                            <div class="small-box bg-success-gradient">
                                                <div class="inner">
                                                    <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>
                                                            <h4>Room No: <span class="room_no"> <%#Eval("Roomno")%> </span></h4>
                                                        </th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Booking-ID :</td>
                                      <td class="txtBI1"><asp:Label ID="lblRID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BookingId")%>'></asp:Label> </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>NAME :</td>
                                                        <td class="txtcustname"><%#Eval("Name")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr hidden="">
                                                        <td>CHECK-IN :</td>
                                                      <td class="txtcin1"><%#Eval("cin")%></td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                                                   <td>CHECK-OUT :</td>
                                                <td class="txtcout2" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bolder;"><%#Eval("cout")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>BALANCE :</td>
                                                        <td class="txtbal"><%#Eval("BALANCE")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr hidden="">
                                                        <td>No. Of Days</td>
                                                        <td class="txtNOD1"><%#Eval("NumberOfDays")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr hidden="">
                                                        <td></td>
                                                        <td class="txtAdvance1"><%#Eval("AdvanceAmount")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr hidden="">
                                                        <td>Extras</td>
                                                        <td class="txtExtras"><%#Eval("ExtraBedPerson")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr hidden="">
                                                        <td>TotalAmount</td>
                                                        <td class="txtTotalA"><%#Eval("TotalAmount")%></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                        <tr hidden="">
                                                        <td>File Path</td>
                                                        <td class="txtImgPath"><%#Eval("FilePath")%></td>
                                                    </tr>                                                            
                                                </table>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm txtPaidAmt" name="txtpa" />
                                                </div> 
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="a2" runat="server" CssClass="small-box-footer chkmodal" data-toggle="modal" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="a2_Click3" data-target="#ChkModal" Style="font-weight: bold"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Check Out</asp:LinkButton>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code used to bind repeater control in Page_Load Event:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Booking where status='1'", constring);        
    sda.Fill(dt);
    Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Code used to build QueryString:

```
protected void a2_Click3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
    string BID = ac.Encrypt((item.FindControl("lblRID") as Label).Text);
    bidr = BID.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you set the querystring and what the value of `bidr` is when you debug?

Comment: I use the textbox value to build the QueryString as while redirecting to another page, I use this line Response.Refirect(“BookingReceipt.aspx?id=”, TextBoxName.Text);

Comment: So what does `bidr` have to do with it then? I can't tell what is going on by the details provided but if your textbox value is null you have probably done a postback before you try to read it.

Comment: bidr is just a random public string

Comment: You say "Code used to build QueryString:". You're just throwing us off track if it isn't.

Comment: Tried with bidr but didn’t work so but I forgot to remove that string